# Calculated columns or triggers? table design in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design

Trying to decide the best table structure between two choices:

VALUE column

1. Add a persisted calculated column which is the difference between two columns
   or
2. Add a trigger to populate a fixed column at load time

Same for the second column. .
nchar(1) Y/N values with a non clustered index

large table? not really not more than 3-4 million records for the life of the server expected, maybe 50K a month, 5 years of data.

I am leaning towards a trigger as the table is only loaded once a month, fixed assets, but just interested in others' experience with maintenance vs view query retrieval speeds, or am I overthinking the design?

Comment: "Best" requires metrics. Are you trying to minimize storage space? Improve the performance of a _specific_ set of queries? Optimize the performance of `insert` statements? Start by reading [this](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: answer is computed columns after testing, less maintenance and speed is inconsequential. . .   Thanks to @HABO

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the calculated column. Why? *Maintainability*.

It's easier for the next person working on your code to understand. When they look at your table definition, they can see your logic. If you use a trigger, they have to know the trigger is there to understand your logic. A lot of database maintenance takes place, sadly, in a panic at zero-dark-thirty. Clarity is very helpful.

You can put indexes on persisted calculated columns without any trouble. So, handling queries efficiently is, as usual, a question of creating appropriate indexes.  SSMS suggests indexes when you rightclick and check "Show Actual Execution Plan".